# Crontab won't run command @reboot

Tags: python, cron

I run jupyter noteboook on a server.

To start it, I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec &> /home/user/logfile2.txt

echo 'running jup.sh' >> /home/user/logfile2.txt

cd /home/user/jup
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
pipenv run jupyter notebook &
```

My `sudo crontab` file looks like:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /usr/scripts/jup.sh
```

It has also looked like:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && /usr/scripts/jup.sh &    -or-
@reboot sleep 20 && /home/user/jup.sh &      -or- 
@reboot (sleep 20 && /usr/scripts/jup.sh) > /dev/null
```

The script will output the file echo portion of the file, and I've echo'd out the working directory as well. As far as I can tell the only thing that doesn't execute is the "pipenv ..." command.

1. I recently upgraded from 17.10, to 18.04 LTS. It used to work under the 'regular' crontab instead of the sudo.
2. The script will start the jupyter notebook at the shell.

**EDIT 1:**
I implemented the recommendations to add the full path for pipenv and for `. /etc/profile`. Neither resolved the issue.

I also deleted the first line of the script and received a mail stating that it couldn't find the full path. It said that it needed the full path. I added the full path and that error went away. Therefore, the full path was part of my problem.

I have a similar script that runs a gunicorn server for a django app. It too works from the shell, but not from @reboot. It too used to work with @reboot.

**Edit 2:**
Email received about the error: (This has been fixed by adding the path)

```
From root@experiments.local  Thu Jun 13 11:25:23 2019
Return-Path: <root@experiments.local>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@experiments.local
Received: by experiments.local (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 05966E144D; Thu, 13 Jun 2019 11:25:23 -0700 (PDT)
From: root@experiments.local (Cron Daemon)
To: root@experiments.local
Subject: Cron <root@experiments> (sleep 20 && /usr/scripts/jup.sh)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20190613182523.05966E144D@experiments.local>
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 11:25:23 -0700 (PDT)

/usr/scripts/jup.sh: 13: /usr/scripts/jup.sh: pipenv: not found
```

Current Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/profile

#exec &> /home/john/logfile2.txt

echo 'running jup.sh' >> /home/john/logfile2.txt

cd /home/john/jup
echo $PWD >> /home/john/logfile2.txt


unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/usr/local/bin/pipenv run jupyter notebook &
```

juypter is an IDE for code exploration. jupyter.org.  I installed it via instructions here: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Root:  I've run it both in sudo crontab and regular crontab. Prior to the last couple of days it has *not* been run as root. As part of troubleshooting, I've run the script in both, to see it makes a difference. It has not.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please also take the [tour] to learn how this community works, and read [ask] for what's expected from you when you ask questions. Not that there's that much wrong with this one :-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the current crontab using the full path to `pipenv`. Try adding ` 2> /tmp/logfile` at the end and then rebooting. Check that `/tmp/logfile` is created and see what the contents are. What is `jupyter`? Does that also need a full path? Is it some module you've installed and, if so, will root have access to it? Why are you running this as root?

Comment: Please also add the verbatim content of that email, so we can see what exactly it says.

Comment: Perhaps this provides some hints that help you with that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391721/pipenv-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

When scripts are executed by cron, usually the environment variables aren't set as you're used to from a login shell. Especially `PATH` is missing, which means the shell can't find the `pipenv` command. Possible solutions:

1. Add the absolute path to external commands. You can find the location of `pipenv` with

   ```
   $ which pipenv
   ```

   In the end that call in your script should read something like

   ```
   /usr/bin/pipenv run jupyter notebook &
   ```
2. Load the complete environment. This is usually achieved by adding the following line to the top of your script:

   ```
   . /etc/profile
   ```

Comment: @terdon @Murphy, I implemented both and it still won't run. The first solution was part of my problem. I deleted the `exec &> /home/user/logfile2.txt` line, and I received local mail indicating pipenv couldn't be found.